# In Hippocms site view in cms differs from live site

Tags: hippocms

The problem is that site view in cms differs from live site itself.

In cms edit mode I've deleted component from container inside page, saved, then published changes. Publish done successfully without any errors and site view in cms looks correctly, i.e. without that component that was removed. But this component still appears in live site.

I can easily fix this problem by removing this component in console. In cms console it can be seen that preview and working configuration differs.

But why this type of desynchronization happens? And what can I do to prevent this kind of problems?

This type of desynchronization happens rarely, but this problem may be very critical in production.

I am using Hippo CMS 10.1.0 Community Edition

Comment: I haven't heard of this problem before. Is it something you can reliably reproduce? Are there any errors in the log? Does this only happen on production or also on other environments? If this isn't something particular to you setup then it sound like a bug.

You might consider upgrading to the latest maintenance release which is 10.2.2. Can't guarantee that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If Your configuraton have been resynchronized, good way is to remove whole preview node. This node will be reconstructed from Your live node when You enter in CMS and turn on edit Mode.